# Why does it take different time to flush same amount of data?

Tags: java, json, performance, io

I have a test code to test json serialization performance with jackson api vs pure StringBuilder. Test1 uses StringBuilder and test2 uses jackson api. Both tests generate 36 millions json string of two fields.

I measured serialization time and flush time. For serialization time, test1 is much faster than test2 due to jackson overhead as expected. However, I am not sure why test1 takes more time to flush same amount of data with same flushing frequency? I appreciate any helps and comments.

Here are the test results in seconds:

test1 (run 7 times):

- serializeTime=12, flushTime=264
- serializeTime=12, flushTime=310
- serializeTime=13, flushTime=288
- serializeTime=13, flushTime=298
- serializeTime=13, flushTime=345
- serializeTime=12, flushTime=342
- serializeTime=12, flushTime=348

test2 (run 7 times):

- serializeTime=65, flushTime=224
- serializeTime=66, flushTime=268
- serializeTime=70, flushTime=289
- serializeTime=71, flushTime=249
- serializeTime=69, flushTime=269
- serializeTime=69, flushTime=266
- serializeTime=70, flushTime=305

Here is the code:

```
public class TestFlush {

// ################## json helper methods ######################
private static final String LCBRACE = "{";
private static final String RCBRACE = "}";
private static final String LSBRACE = "[";
private static final String RSBRACE = "]";
private static final String QUOTE = "\"";
private static final String COLON = ":";
private static final String COMMA = ",";

private static void writeStartObject(StringBuilder json){
    json.append(LCBRACE);
}

private static void writeEndObject(StringBuilder json){
    json.replace(json.length()-1, json.length(), RCBRACE);
}

private static void writeStartArray(StringBuilder json){
    json.append(LSBRACE);
}

private static void writeEndArray(StringBuilder json){
    json.append(RSBRACE);
}

private static void writeArrayFieldStart(StringBuilder json, String fieldName){
    writeFieldName(json, fieldName);
    writeStartArray(json);
}

private static void writeFieldName(StringBuilder json, String fieldName){
    json.append(QUOTE).append(fieldName).append(QUOTE).append(COLON);
}

private static void writeObjectField(StringBuilder json, String fieldName, Object fieldValue){
    writeFieldName(json, fieldName);
    writeObject(json, fieldValue);
}

private static void writeObject(StringBuilder json, Object fieldValue){
    json.append(QUOTE).append(fieldValue).append(QUOTE);
    json.append(COMMA);
}
//###############################################################

static int N = 36000000;
static int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
static int bufFlushSize = ((int)(0.9*BUFFER_SIZE));
static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zz");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    test(false);
    //test(true);
}

private static void test(boolean jackson) throws IOException{
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long serializeTime = 0, flushTime = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        String v1 = format.format(new Date());
        String v2 = i%2==0?"deny":"allow";

        if(jackson)
            serializeTime += serializeCurrentRecord(mapper, baos, v1, v2);
        else
            serializeTime += serializeCurrentRecord(sb, baos, v1, v2);

        baos.write('\n');

        if(baos.size() > bufFlushSize){
            System.out.println("i="+i+", baos.size="+baos.size()+", flushTime="+flushTime);
            flushTime += flush(out, baos);
        }
    }

    flushTime += flush(out, baos);

    System.out.println("serializeTime="+serializeTime/1000000000+", flushTime="+flushTime/1000000000);
}

private static long serializeCurrentRecord(StringBuilder sb, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String v1, String v2) throws IOException{
    long st = System.nanoTime();
    writeStartObject(sb);
    writeObjectField(sb, "f1", v1);
    writeObjectField(sb, "f2", v2);
    writeEndObject(sb);
    baos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
    sb.setLength(0);
    return System.nanoTime() - st;
}

private static long serializeCurrentRecord(ObjectMapper mapper, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String v1, String v2) throws IOException{
    long st = System.nanoTime();
    JsonGenerator jg = mapper.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(baos, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    jg.writeStartObject();
    jg.writeObjectField("f1", v1);
    jg.writeObjectField("f2", v2);
    jg.writeEndObject();
    jg.flush();
    return System.nanoTime() - st;
}

private static long flush(OutputStream out, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) throws IOException{
    long st = System.nanoTime();
    baos.writeTo(out);
    baos.reset();
    out.flush();
    return System.nanoTime() - st; 
}
```

Comment: Your results seem to show that test2 has marginally *quicker* flushing times. I'm confused...

Comment: @Duncan That's a typo, I meant "test1 takes more time to flush". I fixed it.